# How long can a submitted DS-160 be used to schedule a visa appointment in the US consulate?

Tags: visas, h1b-visas, us-visa

I have filled in my DS-160 for my visa application and paid the MRV fees. But appointment slots are still not opened for the dates I want to travel to India. How long can I use the same DS-160 application Id to schedule an appointment? The DS-160 is submitted already - does it get deleted from the system after 30 days?

Comment: The word _visa_ is not an acronym and should not be spelled with all capital letters.  Some forms of the trademark of the financial services company Visa, Inc., but not all of them, are registered as _VISA_.